# Acces to local dumb http git repository via https gateway

Tags: git, nginx, redirect, https, proxy

I have a dumb git repository on http server A where the server is not accessible from internet. I have server B in DMZ that I want to be a gateway to my git repository. The git repository is read-only, no push from internet.

If I go for http, i.e. allow to use `git pull http://serverB/git/project` then the solution is easy, I only need to forward port 80 from B to A.

But how to enable `git pull https://serverB/git/project`?

ServerB has public IP and a coresponding certificate.

Comment: Set up an https proxy (nginx is a common option) to forward https connections from server B port 443 to regular http on server A port 80.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by @larsks, nginx proxy is the easiest way to forward https to http on another server.

Here is the complete solution (the important part of `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`):

```
# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
#
    server {
        listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
        server_name  this_must_be_set_to_registered_public_FQDN;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/your.cert";
        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/your.key";
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
        ssl_ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location /git/ {
            try_files $uri @gitserver;
        }

        location @gitserver {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass http://your.git.server.com;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }

}
```